# Password protecting url / folder with Jetty

Tags: .htaccess, jsp, jetty, password-protection, jetty-8

I'd like to password protect a limited portion of a JSP based website running on Jetty 8.1.

So for the url www.mywebsite.com/protected I want the browser to pop up a user/password entry window, whereas www.mywebsite.com is accessible to everyone.

I know that with Apache this is done with the .htaccess file. Since Jetty runs without Apache I'd like to know what's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsp is just a servlet so you want to configure a security realm protecting that url space in your web.xml file.

Jetty 7, 8

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Realms

Jetty 9

- http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security.html#configuring-security-authentication